# Geometric inequality related with convexity of the boundary

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, convex-geometry, geometric-measure-theory

I'm new to Mathoverflow, so hopefully my question is well-posed.

*My problem states as follows:*

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain with boundary $\partial \Omega$ , $\delta>0$ and $x_0\in\partial\Omega$ be some fixed point. $B_\delta(x_0)$ denotes the open ball around $x_0$ with radius $\delta$. Now suppose that the boundary $\partial\Omega$ is given locally around $x_0$ as a graph of a sufficiently "curved" function. I want to figure out which assumption is needed.

Some words about regularity: to get some first insights let's assume $C^2$-regularity.
Moreover let $\Gamma_\delta = \partial \Omega\cap \partial B_\delta(x_0)$ and $[\Omega_\delta]$ be the parametric minimal surface spanned by $\Gamma_\delta$. This minimal surface can be characterized as a local perimeter minimizer and  is $\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$-a.e. ($\mathcal{H}^{n-1}$ denotes the $(n-1)$-dimensional Hausdorff measure) smooth by standard regularity theory (I've used the book of [Maggi, Sets of Finite perimeter and Geometric Variational problems] )

**Question:** Can we prove an estimate as  follows:
There exist $\gamma\in[0,1)$ and  $\tilde{\delta}>0$ such that
$$(1-\gamma) \mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\partial\Omega\cap B_\delta(x_0)) > \mathcal{H}^{n-1} ([\Omega_\delta])$$
holds for all $0<\delta\leq \tilde{\delta}$. Which assumptions on the parametrisation are necessary?

*What I have done so far:*

- I am able to prove such an inequality for strictly convex boundaries with $\gamma=0$. The main idea is to use the fact $[\Omega_\delta]$ can be viewed as the reduced boundary of a perimeter minimizer of a certain Plateau type Problem in a cylinder, i.e.
  $$ \mathcal{H}^{n-1}([\Omega_\delta])= P(E,C_\delta) \leq P(F,C_\delta)$$
  for any set of finite perimeter $F$ such that $E\Delta F \subset \subset C_\delta$ where $C_\delta = \tilde{\Sigma}\times[-\delta,\delta]$ is some cylinder where $\Sigma\subset\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ is the domain of the local parametrization and $\tilde{\Sigma}$ is a slight increase of $\Sigma$ in normal direction for technical reasons.  Choosing $F$ to be a suitable subcylinder gives the inequality $$P(E,C_\delta)\leq \mathcal{H}^{n-1}(\Sigma)<\int_\Sigma \sqrt{1+|\nabla\phi|^2}dx.$$ Unfortunately I'm not able to generalise this.

*Some ideas:*

- Work with a principal coordinate system, i.e. a coordinate system where the 2nd derivative of $\phi$ is diagonal with eigenvalues $\kappa_i$, i.e. the principal curvatures.
- I think that strict convexity is not enough, so I think $\alpha$-strong convexity may  be the right concept, i.e. the parameterisation $\phi$ should satisfy
  $$
  \phi(\lambda x+(1-\lambda) y)+\frac{\alpha}{2}\lambda(1-\lambda) \|x-y\|^2\leq \lambda\phi(x)+(1-\lambda) \phi(y).
  $$
  For such a Function we get a lower bound for the principal curvatures.

*Some problems:*

- The area of the graph involves the gradient, but the convexity assumption (or more general the principal curvatures) provide informations about the second derivatives.
- How to find a good competitor / good perturbation of the minimal surface to get the desired inequality?

**Related question:** Is there some connection between the local area of some hypersurface (or more general of a submanifold) with the local curvature?

Thanks a lot in advance! I'm happy about every comment, idea, reference request (maybe such a question has been already treated in the literature) or even some counterexample.

Comment: It's a bit hard for me to understand the question but it seems to me there's no hope of getting such an inequality as delta goes to zero. The point is that the boundary and the plateau minimizer both become close to a flat disk. Did you work this out where Omega is a round ball in R2? In this case the minimal surface will just be a line segment.

Comment: @OtisChodosh Thanks for your quick comment! I see your point and yes the case delta goes to zero destroys any hope of such an inequality.

Comment: At the beginning I needed to have such an inequality just for one fixed radius delta (which should be true, in case of strong convexity) and after choosing all quantities it resulted in allowing to have it for smaller radii, which does not work in general as your simple R2 example shows already. I have to figure out how to fix this step.

Comment: At least for a sufficiently nice looking $\Omega$, there might be some information in the excess volume as well. In the worst case, $\partial \Omega \cap B_\delta$ might be the area-minimizer for a fixed volume $\Omega \cap B_\delta$ (which also involves curvature as a Lagrange-multiplier), while your $[\Omega_\delta]$ is a minimizer without such a volume constraint. There is a sheer endless amount of literature on (reverse, relative) isoperimetric inequalities that could provide some ideas here, in particular since they often quantify the error in terms of additional quantities.

Comment: @mlk Thanks for your comment! This sounds really interesting for me, because as I cannot rule out the delta to zero case, it would be nice to have some quantitative information. I'll definitely look it up! Do you have some special reference in your mind?

Comment: I don't have any special reference in mind, but the names I would associate with these ideas are Fusco, Maggi and Pratelli and their respective coauthors, so that might be a start. Though most of their results probably would need to be adapted a bit to fit in your context.

Comment: @mlk I was able to find some interesting papers about this stuff yesterday, so thanks again! I have to figure out, whether i can use them or not. The only thing I've missed so far were some details about the connection between the minimizers and constrained minimizers via Lagrange-Multipliers. Maybe someone know s a little bit more about it or some references.